# SVN server Auto Synchronization with Local Database @ Runtime

Tags: database, svn, tortoisesvn, projectlocker

I am using ProjectLocker as my SVN server.Stuck at Files Synchronization at run time with Local DB Files. I am using Tortoise SVN.

Comment: Please elaborate on what are you doing and what you are trying to achieve. Your question is not clear.

Comment: I work at ProjectLocker and may be able to assist.  Can you tell us:
1) What files you mean (dump files or actual DB files), 2) Where your working copy lives relative to these files, 3) Whether the other files are on the same server, 4) Whether the files you're attempting to sync are binary, 5) Whether your goal is to just keep a backup of these files or something else.  The answers to these questions can help us get you the most effective answer.

Comment: @brokenbeatnik: 3>All the files are in the server,1> just trying to upgrade with the sql (db files) and merge them with the others.Also how can i merge files ,itz showing an error 'file_name already exists' while exporting the files. I want to update a working copy each day.  4> What do you mean by binary files? i want to update all type of files that we update thru FTP, php,css DB files everything.I m a newbie in this. Please xplain it will be very kind of you.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it sounds like you may not be familiar with some version control concepts.  For new Subversion users, I recommend [Chapter 1](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.html) of the [Version Control With Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) book.  This will explain what a working copy is in more detail, and how Subversion keeps your data.  Chapter 2 has more information on a basic work cycle.  [ProjectLocker](http://www.projectlocker.com) takes care of all the svnadmin steps for you, so you can ignore those and look at how to check out, update, and commit.

The first thing you should do is to create a staging directory where you keep any files that you're doing development on.  You may need to copy your PHP, CSS, DB files and so on to that location.  You then run the TortoiseSVN equivalent for svn import to upload all the files to your server.  Once you've imported them, back up the directory you just created, and create an empty working directory.  Run the TortoiseSVN equivalent of Subversion checkout and you will pull down all the files in your repository.  Once you have that, Subversion will take care of identifying which changes can be merged and which will need manual intervention as you make changes, run updates to pull changes from other users, and commit.

If you wish to upload files to a remote location after commits and you have a paid account, you can use ProjectLocker's remote deployment solution to FTP a particular Subversion directory over to your actual server for deployment.

I apologize if this is a little vague, but the scope of your question is quite broad, and so I wanted to give you as concise an answer as possible while still addressing your needs.